# REST WebAPI - What about actions and sub controllers?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

We've got a RESTful WebAPI service here and I've been wondering about what to do to structure my code and routing to cope with the following:

```
http://myapi/customer/1/files
```

and

```
http://myapi/customer/1/files/3
```

So I basically have a customer controller that manages customer information, and a file controller that manages file information, and if I want all the files for customer 1, I might do the first request.

I don't really want to manage it in the context of the customer, so when my GET on the file is focused on an ID for a file, I would have to overload it and do

```
http://myapi/files/?customer=1&files=all
```

It seems a bit less clean than the first solution?

At the moment I have the following:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: SubController, routeTemplate: "{entity}/{entityid}/{controller}/", defaults: null);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: SubControllerAndId, routeTemplate: "{entity}/{entityid}/{controller}/{id}", defaults: null);
```

Which resolves to the `FilesController` when sending `http://myapi/customer/1/files` :

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string entity, string entityid, int id)
    {
        var item = "Hello " + entity + " " + entityid + " "  + id;
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, item);
    }

[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string entity, string entityid)
    {
        var item = "Hello " + entity + " " + entityid;
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, item);
    }
```

This works and passes in `customer` as the entity and `1` as the entity id, but it doesn't feel like the best solution, is there a better way to do this, is this wrong?

Comment: I think you meant the opposite, http://myapi/files/?customer=all&files=1, right?

Comment: @PedroWerneck No, what I wrote is correct :) -  Get all files for customer 1

Comment: then your phrase before it is wrong, because your GET is focused on the ID for a customer. Anyway, your problem really isn't clear for me.

Comment: You can take a look at Web API attribute routing sample over here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/WebApiAttributeRoutingSample/WebApiAttributeRoutingSample/Controllers/Api/CustomersController.cs ... In this example we use model of Customers and Ordes. This sample uses both traditional and attribute routing together.

Comment: @PedroWerneck Assume the suffixed data of /files to be an extension of the customer entity, but existing within the files domain. Should it exist on the customer controller as a function, or within the files controller as an overloaded get? It strikes me that it could logically exist in either, but it feels right to put file based logic in a file controller. How should I setup routing for this? as above? Has anyone else setup similar?

Comment: Thanks Kiran, that's a good example there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kiran is right. Nuget Attribute Routing seems to be what are you looking for.

Heres's how it will looks like:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [GET("api/customer/{id}/files")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
    //code
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [GET("api/customer/{id}/files/{fileId}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id, int fileId)
    {
    //code
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: If you can use Web API 2, this is already included (they just included the NuGet package into Web Api).

Comment: NOTE: I was referring to Web API 2's in-built attribute routing :-)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, so presumably the 'right' way is to put the logic for any sub items within the entities controller? How does this scale, if I had a few different 'actions' that existed as other controllers already? Orders, files, user data, etc.?

Comment: @danielrozo: Please note that even though Web API 2's attribute routing started from the attribute routing nuget package, there have been major design changes since then.

Comment: @KiranChalla yeah, the "just" makes it sound bad in English, not the intention, though, I <3 Web API :).

Comment: @KiranChalla Quick question - what are the differences between Web API 2's attribute routing and the Web API attribute routing NuGet package?